# Tkinter gives no attribute 'getvar' nor 'eval' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, pysimplegui

My code stopped working quite literally overnight, due to an issue with Tkinter.

I'm using PySimpleGui for my project, which was working the previous day.

When I run my program it showed the bellow error:

```
  File "E:/Projekty Python/dcs_assistant/gui_and_video.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
  File "C:\Users\pawni\Miniconda3\envs\dcs_assistant\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .PySimpleGUI import *
  File "C:\Users\pawni\Miniconda3\envs\dcs_assistant\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 125, in <module>
    tclversion_detailed = tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')
  File "C:\Users\pawni\Miniconda3\envs\dcs_assistant\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2354, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: module '_tkinter' has no attribute 'eval'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Line 125 is this:

```
tclversion_detailed = tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')
```

This, as per Tkinter documentation, should simply return the version of Tkinter library (https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html).

When I ran a dummy program using just Tkinter to test if Tkinter alone works. I got another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Projekty Python/dcs_assistant/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    tk = tkinter.Tk()
  File "C:\Users\pawni\Miniconda3\envs\dcs_assistant\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2272, in __init__
    self._loadtk()
  File "C:\Users\pawni\Miniconda3\envs\dcs_assistant\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2286, in _loadtk
    tk_version = self.tk.getvar('tk_version')
AttributeError: module '_tkinter' has no attribute 'getvar'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code for the dummy program was:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *
tk = tkinter.Tk()
frame = tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=2)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Hello, World")
label.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Exit", command=tk.destroy)
button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
tk.mainloop()
```

I tried to uninstall and re-install Tkinter again using both pip and conda. No joy.

Comment: What I concered is the exception message, why not the "AttributeError: `'_tkinter.tkapp' object` has no attribute ..." ? but `module '_tkinter'` ? self.tk is a `<_tkinter.tkapp object >`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the case. Both program crash at two different steps in Tkinter, but both relating to version check. Not sure how or why. Line 2286 in in _loadtk says: ```tk_version = self.tk.getvar('tk_version')```, line 2354 in  __getattr__ goes   ```def __getattr__(self, attr):
        "Delegate attribute access to the interpreter object"
        return getattr(self.tk, attr)```